# SharePoint APPCRASH errors in event viewer

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, sharepoint-calendar, content-migration

we have just migrated a SharePoint 2010 site to 16 using Sharegate, the site is now live but the event log on the server is full of Event 1001 APPCRASH events, and some components on the site have stopped working. -

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: csc.exe
P2: 4.6.1085.0
P3: 57a5020d
P4: KERNELBASE.dll
P5: 6.3.9600.18438
P6: 57ae642e
P7: c0000142
P8: 00000000000ecdd0
P9: 
P10:

Attached files:

> C:\Users\SP-P-POOL\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7333.tmp.appcompat.txt
>
> C:\Users\SP-P-POOL\AppData\Local\Temp\WER7392.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_csc.exe_5594cdc2f7763ba8fca4af64b48872348a2de81_28f8e291_cab_acf5739f\memory.hdmp
>
> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_csc.exe_5594cdc2f7763ba8fca4af64b48872348a2de81_28f8e291_cab_acf5739f\triagedump.dmp

These files may be available here:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_csc.exe_5594cdc2f7763ba8fca4af64b48872348a2de81_28f8e291_cab_acf5739f
>
> Analysis symbol: 
>   Rechecking for solution: 0
>   Report Id: 68828d71-f8fd-11e6-80ea-005056b229fe
>   Report Status: 4
>   Hashed bucket:

Also, this error follows -

> Faulting application name: csc.exe, version: 4.6.1085.0, time stamp:
>   0x57a5020d Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.3.9600.18438, time stamp: 0x57ae642e Exception code: 0xc0000142 Fault offset: 0x00000000000ecdd0 Faulting process id: 0x48c0 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d28d0a2ad60164 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Faulting
>   module path: KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   68828d71-f8fd-11e6-80ea-005056b229fe Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Weird things are happening on the site as well, such as the calendar date picker in this case (error comes up as I click the calendar icon) -

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? Once rebooted, the site will work perfectly for a few hours, then the APPCRASH events will re-appear. Thank you!